# Digit Square Sum

Tags: java, recursion, sum, digits, square

Dr Phan has found that by performing digitSquareSum() multiple times, two numbers get back to their original number:
•   1 -> 1

•   89 -> 145 -> 42 -> 20 -> 4 -> 16 -> 37 -> 58 -> 89
She asked Ken to identify which of the original numbers, between 1 and 500, will arrive at 1 after multiple iterations of performing digitSquareSum().

Comment: Have you made an attempt to solve this at all? Also this seems to be a homework question, I would recommend reading [this article](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions) about homework questions.

Answer (score -1):

The list of numbers is as follows: 
[1,   7,  10,  13,  19,  23,  28,  31,  32,  44,  49,  68,  70,
79,  82,  86,  91,  94,  97, 100, 103, 109, 129, 130, 133, 139,
167, 176, 188, 190, 192, 193, 203, 208, 219, 226, 230, 236, 239,
262, 263, 280, 291, 293, 301, 302, 310, 313, 319, 320, 326, 329,
331, 338, 356, 362, 365, 367, 368, 376, 379, 383, 386, 391, 392,
397, 404, 409, 440, 446, 464, 469, 478, 487, 490, 496]

**As this is a suspected homework problem, I will refrain from providing any code as of right now.**